# How to run android app during powersave mode

Tags: android, power-saving

I am trying to run an app while it is in power saver mode, does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: what do you mean "while it is in power save mode"? Does your app don't run in power-save mode right now?

Comment: well the idea is to run the app when the phones screen turns off after a period of time. i asked on a different post how to use this mode and its in powermanager class but i need this app im working on to run while the phone turns off its screen, ya get me? thanks for the reply by the way mate

Comment: the best way to deal with this is to run a background service in your application. That service will run even if your screen is Off.

Comment: ill have a look into that, thanks very much mate

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @waqaslam, the app needs to be run as a background service. Details can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html